# Postman can upload file to a Node api. But Not with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, axios, mern

Redux Code

```
export const uploadImage = data => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
    };

    try {
        const res = await axios.post("/api/profile/upload", data, config);
        // const res = await axios.post("/api/profile/upload", data, {
        //  headers: {
        //      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        //  }
        // });
        console.log(res);
        dispatch({
            type: AVATAR_UPLOAD,
            payload: res.data
        });
    } catch (err) {
        const errors = err.response.data.errors;

        if (errors) {
            errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, "danger")));
        }

        dispatch({
            type: PROFILE_ERROR,
            payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
        });
    }
};
```

React Code

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append("file", avatar);
uploadImage(data);
```

I get bad request message, req.files is empty 
I try to upload file with Postman same configuration,it seems api works but can't upload with react formdata.

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you get data if you do `console.log(data)` in `uploadImage` function?

Comment: Yes I get FormData object in uploadImage function.I also tried to make request directly from react component it didn't work as well. Somehow axios can't post FormData .

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);
const res = await axios.post("/api/profile/upload", formData, config);
```